# getting max value of a timestamp column as subquery in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a timestamp columns with name `start_dt` and `end_dt`  in my hive table1 and the table will always have only one record.

In table2 I have a date column called `load_dt`.

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
select * from table2 where load_dt between (select cast(max(start_dt) to date) from table1) and (select cast(max(end_dt) to date) from table1)
```

However the above query is failing.
what would be correct query to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have sub queries are not supported in Hive where clause.

Please check the [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)